# How do you know if you're using the CuDNN version of LSTM or GRU in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

A nice feature of TensorFlow 2.0: the [new LSTM layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) now automatically decides whether to use the CuDNN implementation or not (the same goes for [GRU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GR) layers). But their use depends on more than the GPU; there are other arguments that need to be set (e.g., `unroll=False`).

I'm using tensorflow-gpu with a GPU (not a very powerful one), and my RNNs are slow as molasses. I'd like to know for sure that I'm running the CuDNN implementation. Is there any place in the logs to look?

I've also used [tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM), which is just as slow for me. Can I be sure that this is using the CuDNN implementation, or might it back off to something else under certain conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM`, it's definitely using the cuDNN implementation. There's no backoff in there.